# Retina display compatible Python IDLE?

Tags: macbook-pro, python, display

On my Retina MacBook Pro, the Python IDLE development environment has blurry, non-retina text.

Is there a way I can make the text retina?

IDLE:

[image: Screenshot of IDLE]

Comment: Which app is actually experiencing poor resolution? Is there an actual application called "Python"?

Comment: Yes .......... http://www.python.org

Comment: What @DanJ is asking is that in the terminal, where python is often run, everything should look fine, because the Terminal app is responsible for rendering text, and is retina compatible. Using python, ruby, perl, anything from the terminal should not make a difference. Are you talking about a Python IDE, or third party terminal app? How about a screenshot demonstrating your problem?

Comment: Python IDLE. Terminal does not print characters in colors unfortunately, otherwise I would use it rather than IDLE. Ill post a pic in a bit

Comment: What do you mean, Terminal doesn't print color characters? Are you saying you want syntax highlighting? Or colored output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment this isn't likely to be fixable, unless you're fairly comfortable with OS X development and want to rewrite parts of the underlying GUI library.

According to [this bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue15587) on [Python.org](http://python.org/), it's an issue with the [TkInter](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) GUI library, which IDLE apparently makes use of. TkInter in turn is based on [Tk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tk_%28framework%29), which is a cross-platform GUI toolkit, which means it almost certainly doesn't use the standard OS X text renderer, which is the only way to get "free" Retina text.

As an alternative, perhaps look at ways to make the default python shell or [IPython](http://ipython.org) running in Terminal more useful to you?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say [segiddins](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/17218/segiddins) has it almost right, with a couple of slight adjustments that made that solution work perfectly for me:

1. Copy IDLE.app to the desktop.
2. Right-click the copied IDLE.app and select `Show Package Contents`.
3. Open `Contents/info.plist`.
4. Add the following two lines...

   `<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>`

   `<true/>`

   ...to the end of the plist file, but before the last two lines (`</dict>`
   `</plist>`).
5. Save the plist.
6. Replace the original IDLE.app with IDLE.app you just modified.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do `Show Package Contents` on the .app bundle.
2. Open `Contents/info.plist`
3. Add

   `<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>`

   `<string>True</string>`

   To the end of the plist file, but before the last two lines (`</dict></plist>`)
4. Save the plist and launch the app!

Comment: That did not work :(

Comment: I guess it doesn't use a native text rendered then.

Comment: If I clicked on get-info, the option to `open in Low Resolution` is checked and locked !!

Comment: Is this after you made the change to the plist?

Comment: Before and after, the setting wont change

Comment: Darn. sorry, since I dont have a rMBP there isn't much more I can come up with.